# Django - change datafield on database

Tags: django, ajax, get

i am creating a real estate website in Django.
I want users to insert/delete images for their properties. It´s all working as expected, except the delete images.

In my views.py i have the code:

```
listing = Listing.objects.get(id=1511)
            if listing:
                listing.photo_5 = None
                listing.save(['photo_5'])
                return True
```

photo_5 is an Imagefield and i want to change the value of that field in database to None.

I am saving the image to media folder and save the url in database.

`photo_5 = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d/', blank=True)`

Then when the user clicks in trash can icon, i have an ajax request (working and receives response from view) to delete the image from database. But there is the problem, i am not able to update the url in database or to delete. I already tried with update

`Listing.objects.all().filter(id = 1511).update(photo_5 = None)`

It seems that i can not change the value of photo_5.

Why is not changing?

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: Are you sure the object 1511 exists when using `Listing.objects.all().filter(id=1511).update(photo_5=None)`?

Comment: You don't have to use all(). Listing.objects.filter(id = 1511).update(photo_5 = None). I tried this code and it's working. Check if id=1511 exists?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The object 1511 exists, of course the id (1511) and field name (photo_5) should be a GET parameter, but i use harcoded for example. And i already try with all(), without all(), with update(), with delete(), with save(), and on the database the url persists.